# How can i paste copied links each on new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got links of all google search results. i have checker, which link i mark, i can copy them. my code works well, but i want that every link i get will be on new line.
...
can someone help me please? i tried to add `"<br>"` but it does not do anything;

here is my code

```
$( ".copy" ).click(function() {
                    var inp = $("<input>");
                    $("body").append(inp);
                    var str = ""
                    var br = document.createElement('br');
                    $('a').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {                     
                        str+= $(this).attr('href') + br ;
                    });

                    inp.val(str).select();
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    inp.remove();
                })
```

Comment: Try changing to str+= $(this).attr('href') + '\n';

Comment: it doesnot do anything

Comment: @SalomeSulaberidze From your profile you have never accepted an answer. To accept an answer, hover beside the answer and you'll see a checkmark. Click on it. Answer accepted. Accepting answers gains you reputation (as well as goodwill)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line 
           //str+= $(this).attr('href') + br ;
                    });
       To this:

```
     str+= $(this).attr('href') + "<br>" ;
                });
```

Comment: You created a br element, you should append it using this syntax: someElement.appendChild(br);

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answer and then realised you wanted you had an 'onclick' event (so i created a button). The answer is simpler than you it may seem. There's an [after()](https://api.jquery.com/after/) method in jquery, handy for just a case such as this.

However, as you're appending on each click of copy, you may want to add a check to see if there is already a break after the link (to append only to the links that have no break), or add a class to indicate that indicates the break has been added , and use `:not` (just a thought. Otherwise you could feasibly wind up with a lot of breaks!

If you wanted to break them up not on-click (e.g. on document ready) then there would be less issue.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".copy").click(function() {
  var inp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(inp);
  var str = ""
  var br = document.createElement('br');

  /*I took the filter out for demo purposes)*/
  $("a").after(br);
  
  inp.val(str).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  inp.remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a href="#">Hello</a><a href="#">Home</a>

</body>
<br><br>
<button class="copy">Copy</button>
```